# React Native: How to get list of available wifi networks in iOS and android devices in react native?

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios

***react-native-wifi-manager*** and ***react-native-android-wifi*** can be used only for android devices. I am looking for a list of available wifi network in both **android and ios**.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Programmatically connecting to WiFi networks on iOS is not possible. You can only guide the user to the settings but you won't ever get the list of wifi's networks.

Comment: not true. since IOS 11. you can connect to but not list.